# Java EE Websocket: How to send keep sending data without receiving message?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, twitter, websocket, java-ee-7

**What I want?**
I am trying to write an application where client sends a query and based on the query server gets twitter-stream and pushes to client.

**What I have?**
I have a simple structure in place where client can connect to server and server responds back

**TweetStreamServer**

```
package com.self.tweetstream;

import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/tweets")
public class TweetStreamServer {
    @OnMessage
    public String tweets(final String message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

**TweetStreamClient**

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class TweetStreamClient {
    public static CountDownLatch latch;
    public static String response;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        try{
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello World!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void printTweets(final String tweet) {
        System.out.println("Tweet:" + tweet);
        response = tweet;
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

**TweetStreamTest**

```
@Test
    public void test() throws URISyntaxException, IOException, DeploymentException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("URI: " + getEndpointUrl());
        TweetStreamClient.latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        Session session = connectToServer(TweetStreamClient.class, "tweets");
        assertNotNull(session);
        assertTrue(TweetStreamClient.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertEquals("Hello World!", TweetStreamClient.response);
    }
```

**Question**
I am confused how can I now send continuous tweets that I receive from Twitter because my server method as per API is

```
       @OnMessage
        public String tweets(final String message) {
            return message;
        }
```

This means it expects a message in order return anything.

How can I send on-coming data from Twitter send to client?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
@OnMessage
public void tweets(final String message, Session client) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    int i = 0;
    for (Session peer : client.getOpenSessions()) {
        while (i < 10) {
            System.out.println("sending ...");
            peer.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello");
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks to [Arun Gupta](https://twitter.com/arungupta) for helping through his tweets :)

Comment: please make sure that you put try-catch block INSIDE the loop - you don't want to skip other connected session when one is broken for some reason.